# ContextCompat.registerReceiver() - what is considered "other apps"'s actions and "system"'s actions? (RECEIVER_EXPORTED/RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED flass)

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast, android-13

So with Android 13 we get the following warning when using the following method:

```
context.registerReceiver(
    /* receiver = */ receiver,
    /* filter = */ intentFilter,
)
```

> receiver is missing RECEIVER_EXPORTED or RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED flag
> for unprotected broadcasts registered for an IntentFilter that cannot
> be inspected by lint

[image]

It's known that we have the following new method from `ContextCompat` class which requires us to set `ContextCompat.RECEIVER_EXPORTED` or `ContextCompat.RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED`

```
ContextCompat.registerReceiver(
    /* context = */ context,
    /* receiver = */ receiver,
    /* filter = */ intentFilter,
    /* flags = */ ContextCompat.RECEIVER_EXPORTED
)
```

`ContextCompat.RECEIVER_EXPORTED` means the following:

> Flag for registerReceiver: The receiver can receive broadcasts from
> other Apps. Has the same behavior as marking a statically registered
> receiver with "exported=true"

`ContextCompat.RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED` means the following:

> Flag for registerReceiver: The receiver cannot receive broadcasts from
> other Apps. Has the same behavior as marking a statically registered
> receiver with "exported=false"

I need to subscribe for the following broadcast actions:

```
Intent.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED
Intent.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED
Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED
Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG
BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED
BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED
```

I found out that for the following broadcast actions I can subscribe only if I specify `ContextCompat.RECEIVER_EXPORTED`:

```
BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED
BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED
```

And for the following broadcast actions I can subscribe with both `ContextCompat.RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED` and `ContextCompat.RECEIVER_EXPORTED`

```
Intent.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED
Intent.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED
Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED
Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG
```

What's the difference and I how will I know it if I don't test it like this?

So Bluetooth broadcast actions are considered as "**Other Apps**" and power/battery/headset_plug boradcast actions are considered as "**System**" and that's why they don't require `ContextCompat.RECEIVER_EXPORTED` and can work with just `ContextCompat.RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED`?

But then I checked the following link https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/reference/broadcast-intents-31

and found out that Bluetooth broadcast actions are also considered as "**System**" ones... Though it's `System Broadcast Intents (API Level 31)`, I could not find a page with higher API level, there are only 30 and 31 pages

Is this a bug in Android or what am I missing? I need to subscribe to all these broadcast actions and I thought that they are all "**system**" ones, they are not from some third party apps, so that's why I wanted to use `ContextCompat.RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED` for each one but then I found out that in this case I can't subscribe to Bluetooth broadcast actions

p.s. tested on a build with 33 target/compile API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Based on](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/14/behavior-changes-14#system-broadcasts)

> Exception for receivers that receive only system broadcasts If your
> app is registering a receiver only for system broadcasts through
> Context#registerReceiver methods, such as Context#registerReceiver(),
> then it shouldn't specify a flag when registering the receiver

So it means if we register for system broadcasts only then we can continue using `Context.registerReceiver()` instead of `ContextCompat.RECEIVER_EXPORTED`

But still there will be the following warning:

[image]

I have already downloaded the latest studio...

Android Studio Hedgehog | 2023.1.1

But it's fine, it just mentions potentional problems when using non-system broadcasts with no flags.

So we should keep in mind that `RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED` won't work for all system broadcasts, so better register it without flags (or use it with `RECEIVER_EXPORTED`) and for some reason `RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED` still works for some system broadcasts...

Also [here](https://developer.android.com/develop/background-work/background-tasks/broadcasts#context-registered-receivers) it says we can use `RECEIVER_EXPORTED` for system and other apps' broadcasts:

[image]